# OpenGL ES - Simple 2D issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am starting with the topic of OpenGL ES in Android programming and just wanted to create a simple 2D Application with some balls... When I did this with usual OpenGL it was quite simple to draw circles and let them move until the border and all this stuff...

But in OpenGL ES everything looks very different, so I cant find a solution to just set the camera in a position that it simulates me a 2D surface for a simple game where I can set the border to maybe 800px and if the ball comes there I just say "collision" and handle that. But I am pretty sure that there is a solution for that, so can anybody maybe just give me a small example or maybe even a link for setting up a simple OpenGL 2D application? All those that I found were just introduction to 3D and didnt tell me what I really want to know.

Comment: 2D is just a special case of 3D. What exactly do you need to know which is so much different in the 3D case?

Comment: I just want a surface of a fixed width and height where I can draw some 2d objects like circles and can locate them by the size of the surface, so that I can detect collision with the border of the surface, you know?

Comment: Well, the principle is the same as when you did it with (old) desktop GL: you need to set up a orthogonal projection which will establish some pixel coordinates you can work with. However, things do look much more complicated since the matrix stack and the builtin functions like `glOrtho` are gone, and you have to use shaders, and the immediate mode `glBegin()/glEnd()` drawing is gone. However, all these topic are covered in modern GL and GLES tutorials. Your question is far too broad to be answerable in this format.